# Windows Driver certification

Tags: windows, sdk, driver, hlk

I have a Windows USB driver that was developed and signed about ten years ago. It consists of an Inf file with its associated Cat file, and a Sys file. Now I need to make an update to the drivers Inf file in order to change some PID values. If I try to change the Inf file, generate a new Cat file and sign that without doing any changes to the Sys file, Windows gives me an error 52 when I try to install the newly certified Inf/Cat file.

Will I need to recertify my Sysfile if I want to change the Inf file for it to work in Windows, or is it possible to just create new Inf and Cat files, certify them and keep the old certification of the Sysfile?

Comment: fyi wrong site - this is not a programming question and is off-toic here. Probably best to ask on [su], as advised in the [tag:windows] tag description.